# PBO not working Properly in Integrated GPU

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, pbo

For benchmarking purpose lets take this famous [PBO Read-back code](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/files/pboPack.zip).

**Problem:**

1. Using PBO is having no effect in my PC. Even with Latest driver Update & correct Pixel format BGRA.

**Update 1: I have also tried the same example with 3 PBO's. But there is no difference even then.**

NOTE:Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3470S CPU @ 2.90GHz, 2901 Mhz, 4 Core(s),
Video Card : Intel(R) HD Graphics 2500

```
PBO: off  
Read Time: 9 ms
Process Time: 2 ms
Transfer Rate: 39.5 Mpixels/s. (45.0 FPS)

PBO: on 
Read Time: 7 ms
Process Time: 2 ms
PBO: on Transfer Rate: 38.8 Mpixels/s. (44.2 FPS)
```

UPDATE 2: **PBO is working correctly in External GPU & also in Intel i-7 series.**

PC config:
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz, 3400 Mhz, 4 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s),Video Card: Geforce 210. So it turns out to be the **Problem with Integrated GPU & External GPU**. I believe this will be a useful Hint for lot of People who are wondering why their code is not working!

```
PBO: on 
PBO: on Read Time: 0.06 ms
Process Time: 2 ms
Transfer Rate: 112.4 Mpixels/s. (127.9 FPS)

PBO: off 
Read Time: 4 ms
Process Time: 2 ms
Transfer Rate: 93.3 Mpixels/s. (106.1 FPS)
```

Comment: Did you try yourself? I don't want to sound offensive but this sounds like you're questioning everyone else's competence but you're not willing to do your own research; If you have any benchmarks of your own, add them. Actually, this is rather ill-fitting for stackoverflow, so maybe write an article about your benchmarks and put it online somewhere, then cite it here.

Comment: @Marcus You are also welcome to improve this question to make it better!

Comment: It is likely to be related to having separate GPU/VRAM and integrated one. I see very close results on intel GPU. Will check on separate nvidia card in a few hours.

Comment: @BalajiR yes I see very significant difference on discrete graphics card (64 vs 41 Mpix/s). On integrated GPU, system RAM and VRAM is the same, so CPU can access data directly without using relatively narrow/slow PCIe.

Comment: @keltar Sounds great! it would be great if you can demonstrate that in code as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the [link](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_pbo.html) :

> Mapping PBO ...
>
> Note that if GPU is still working with the buffer object,
>   glMapBufferARB() will not return until GPU finishes its job with the
>   corresponding buffer object. To avoid this stall(wait), call
>   glBufferDataARB() with NULL pointer right before glMapBufferARB().
>   Then, OpenGL will discard the old buffer, and allocate new memory
>   space for the buffer object.

You may need to apply the change proposed above to the code below:

```
// "index" is used to read pixels from framebuffer to a PBO
// "nextIndex" is used to update pixels in the other PBO
index = (index + 1) % 2;
nextIndex = (index + 1) % 2;

// set the target framebuffer to read
glReadBuffer(GL_FRONT);

// read pixels from framebuffer to PBO
// glReadPixels() should return immediately.
glBindBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER_ARB, pboIds[index]);
glReadPixels(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);

// map the PBO to process its data by CPU
glBindBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER_ARB, pboIds[nextIndex]);
glBufferDataARB(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER_ARB, 0, NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW_ARB);
GLubyte* ptr = (GLubyte*)glMapBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER_ARB,
                                        GL_READ_ONLY_ARB);
if(ptr)
{
    processPixels(ptr, ...);
    glUnmapBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER_ARB);
}

// back to conventional pixel operation
glBindBufferARB(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER_ARB, 0);
```